# BigQuery: What's the most efficient way to query a table X times and then flatten results?

Tags: google-bigquery

Objective: Select a COUNT(something) from table_a several times while having different where clauses to later persist (flatten) results into another table.

The desired outcome is something like:

```
ID|Cnt_A|Cnt_B|Cnt_C
1|10|20|40
2|2|12|55
...
```

Where Table_a data looks like something this

```
ID|Field_1|Field_2|Field_3|Field_...
1|True|Something|Else|10|...
1|False|Else|Something|20|...
2|True|Possibly|Positive|30|...
2|False|Might|Negative|40|...
```

My Cnt_A could be a `SELECT COUNT(Field_1) FROM Table_a WHERE Field_1 = True` whereas Cnt_B could be something like `SELECT COUNT(Field_2) FROM Table_a WHERE Field_2 != 'Possibly'`, etc.

In trying to figure out the above, I did not see possible anything that was not computing the three fields in three separate temporary tables that expose both the count and the ID. In such a way, I can do a final SELECT joining the three tables and flatten all into a destination table.

While the outcome I want is achieved, I wonder if there is anything better I can do to obtain the above result.

I have not tried the following yet, though:

```
SELECT t1.Cnt_A, t2.Cnt_B
FROM (SELECT ID, COUNT(Field_A) as cnt 
      FROM ....
      GROUP BY ID HAVING .... MyWhereClause here) t1
JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(Field_A) as cnt 
      FROM ....
      GROUP BY ID HAVING .... MyWhereClause here) t2
ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Would this be a possible better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do all in one shot - use below approach

```
select id, 
  countif(Field_1 = True) as Cnt_A,
  countif(Field_2 != 'Possibly') as Cnt_B,
  countif(Field_3 = 'Positive') as Cnt_C
from your_table
group by id
```